# Laravel 5.6 Auth to different tables in DB

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

Laravel 5.6 uses Auth with its database table - 'users' by default.
I need to create 2 different users - simple user and user admin, so each of them will use there own Auth method and connect to there own database table.

For example: Auth::user(); - with table 'users'
and i need to create another auth, like Auth::admin(); - with table 'admin'

How i can do that? Maybe copy and create another Auth?

(I am using laravel's api and passport).

I don't need to create new fields in the users table. I need to create a new table.

Comment: Or you can just assign roles and permission and make it work from one table

Comment: No, there are to many data in each of tables, so a can't use roles...

Comment: its better to keep it in one table. you can simply add a field like `user_type` for differentiating users.

Comment: in that case, perhaps, you should create a new table as required and call it admin. use different route ie /admin for admins to login and /users for users to login. users  will validate through users table and admins through admins. BUT THIS WILL GIVE YOU A BIG HEADACHE. Better to use a permission and roles, you can always add extra fields in user tables :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a middleware for admin authentication. Do so by typing this:

```
php artisan make:middleware Admin
```

This creates a middleware file called Admin.php

Register the middleware on Kernel.php

```
'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class
```

Add the admin middleware to a route in route.php file

```
get('protected', ['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin'], function() {
    return "this page requires that you be logged in and an Admin";
}]);
```

Add the isAdmin() method to User model for checking if it is admin or not.

```
public function isAdmin()
{
    return $this->admin; // this looks for an admin column in your users table
}
```